# Authenticated flow for AWSIoT iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-iot

I am able to run the IoT Temperature Control Sample provided by Amazon.

Below is the link for the sample app:

[The Amazon IoT Temperature Control Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/IoTTemperatureControl-Sample/Swift)

The app is responding to the AWS IoT in proper manner.

But the app is designed for the Unauthenticated user.
I need to implement the same for the Authenticated user in which the AWS Cognito provides the Access Key,Secret Key and Access Token for the user.
Using those credentials I need to provide access of AWS IoT to that user.

I am not able to get how to do that.

Please help me in achieving the solution.

Comment: This seems to be similar. Does this solve your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301345/connect-to-aws-iot-using-web-socket-with-cognito-authenticated-users?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: Same thing I have to implement but for iOS in Swift 3.That did not resolved my problem as I don't know javascript.