# WebSocket connection failed. Error during WebSocket handshake.Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: websocket, mqtt, amazon-cognito, iot, aws-iot

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/browser/mqtt-explorer/index.js

I'm using the example code from github to connect to my aws iot core.

upon running the code i get the following error

WebSocket connection to "websocket url" failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

i'm using cognito unauthenticated role with full access AWS  IOT policy.

what could be the issue here?

Comment: 403 means forbidden so this is a permissions issue. See a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848195/forbiddenerror-403-when-getshadow-updateshadow-called-in-aws-iot). If not done yet, try following another tutorial that guides you through keys and other setup configurations.

Comment: solved! i changed my  computer timezone to match my aws zone , then it worked!